# Issues rendering characters with diacritics of custom font

Tags: ios, core-text

I have installed a custom font and have tried to render an attributed string created with it using 2 methods:
1. Use a CoreText CTFrame to draw the string
2. In iOS6, using drawing the attributed string directly into the graphics context.

Both methods yield the same issue with characters containing diacritics see attached image (character appears "bold"). I have loaded the same text into a UILabel and the characters displays normally, which rules out any issues with the font itself.

Any advice how this can be fixed would be greatly appreciated please.[image]